# Errors while installing python autopy

Tags: python, autopy

Hey I have looked at and old question here but it doesn't answer my question

I have installed libpng, then try to install autopy and get complie errors.

I am not great at python yet so I am not sure on how to fix them.

```
Ashley:~ ashleyhughes$ sudo easy_install autopy
Searching for autopy
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/autopy/
Reading http://www.autopy.org
Best match: autopy 0.51
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/a/autopy/autopy-0.51.tar.gz#md5=b92055aa2a3712a9c3b4c874014b450e
Processing autopy-0.51.tar.gz
Running autopy-0.51/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-U9uWoj/autopy-0.51/egg-dist-tmp-hdjtIx
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
src/screengrab.c:48:26: warning: implicit declaration of function
      'CGDisplayBitsPerPixel' is invalid in C99
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        bitsPerPixel = (uint8_t)CGDisplayBitsPerPixel(displayID);
                                ^
src/screengrab.c:191:2: warning: 'CGLSetFullScreen' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        CGLSetFullScreen(glContext);
        ^
src/screengrab.c:194:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'glReadBuffer'
      is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        glReadBuffer(GL_FRONT);
        ^
src/screengrab.c:194:15: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GL_FRONT'
        glReadBuffer(GL_FRONT);
                     ^
src/screengrab.c:197:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'glFinish' is
      invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        glFinish();
        ^
src/screengrab.c:199:6: warning: implicit declaration of function 'glGetError'
      is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        if (glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR) return NULL;
            ^
src/screengrab.c:199:22: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GL_NO_ERROR'
        if (glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR) return NULL;
                            ^
src/screengrab.c:207:2: warning: implicit declaration of function
      'glPopClientAttrib' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        glPopClientAttrib(); /* Clear attributes previously set. */
        ^
src/screengrab.c:223:2: warning: implicit declaration of function
      'glPushClientAttrib' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        glPushClientAttrib(GL_CLIENT_PIXEL_STORE_BIT);
        ^
src/screengrab.c:223:21: error: use of undeclared identifier
      'GL_CLIENT_PIXEL_STORE_BIT'
        glPushClientAttrib(GL_CLIENT_PIXEL_STORE_BIT);
                           ^
src/screengrab.c:225:2: warning: implicit declaration of function
      'glPixelStorei' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, BYTE_ALIGN); /* Force alignment. */
        ^
src/screengrab.c:225:16: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT'
        glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, BYTE_ALIGN); /* Force alignment. */
                      ^
src/screengrab.c:226:16: error: use of undeclared identifier
      'GL_PACK_ROW_LENGTH'
        glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ROW_LENGTH, 0);
                      ^
src/screengrab.c:227:16: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GL_PACK_SKIP_ROWS'
        glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_SKIP_ROWS, 0);
                      ^
src/screengrab.c:228:16: error: use of undeclared identifier
      'GL_PACK_SKIP_PIXELS'
        glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_SKIP_PIXELS, 0);
                      ^
src/screengrab.c:235:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'glReadPixels'
      is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        glReadPixels(x, y, width, height,
        ^
src/screengrab.c:236:30: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GL_BGRA'
                     MMRGB_IS_BGR ? GL_BGRA : GL_RGBA,
                                    ^
src/screengrab.c:236:40: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GL_RGBA'
                     MMRGB_IS_BGR ? GL_BGRA : GL_RGBA,
                                              ^
9 warnings and 9 errors generated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Can anyone help. I need autopy as it works on multiple platforms

I used ethan.tira-thompson.com/Mac_OS_X_Ports.html to install libpng

Have xcode installed with command line tools as well

Comment: Just [edit] your own question to add the extra information.

Comment: You seem to be missing OpenGL header files. Did you install Xcode?

Comment: Yeah I have xcode also had to install the xcode commandline tools as clang was missing

Comment: OP: Does any answer here solve your problem?

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem, if you notice all 9 errors are coming from one file:
src/screengrab.c
This file has not been updated to the latest version of OpenGL and there are deprecated methods.  On the autopy github repo there is a bug reported for this [here.](https://github.com/msanders/autopy/pull/27)  The fix/hack suggested there is to add the line:
`#include <OpenGL/gl.h>`

after line 7 in src/screengrab.c.  You are going to have to get the source from Github and alter it locally rather than using easy_install.
Note this is a hack that will get it to compile but the screen grabs will be all black.  Someone needs to spend a few minutes rewriting screengrab.c with up to date methods.

Answer (score 3):

When I added

```
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
```

It did not compile.

So, I took a look though my hard disk, looking for each `gl.h`

So, I tried

```
    #include "/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Headers/gl.h"
```

Then I managed to compile it :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could only install autopy in python 3.8; Else It can't be installed.

Or you can downgrade your autopy version. There is autopy release history:

https://pypi.org/project/autopy/#history

I had also errors while installing autopy, But when I installed python 3.8,
It worked perfectly.

That works - Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

If you have tried this:

$ sudo easy_install autopy

Another option is to compile from the latest source on the GitHub repository:

$ git clone git://github.com/msanders/autopy.git

$ cd autopy

$ python setup.py build

$ python setup.py install

When building from source, make sure to cd out of the autopy directory before attempting to use AutoPy or else it may fail on an ImportError due to Python's relative imports.