# Spynner installation error on Mac OS X 10.9.1

Tags: python, macos, spynner

I can't get to install `spynner` on Mac OS X 10.9.1 (Mavericks). I get the following error:

```
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

to mention that the error is thrown when the `autopy` dependency is installed. I have the Xcode, command line tools installed.

```
cc --version
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix

gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix$
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Please, see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993126/errors-while-installing-python-autopy Please, also include more pieces of information here about the error.

Comment: If you are still having trouble installing autopy, the [answer I posted here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28629870/168594) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, Spynner relies on Autopy, and the installation fails because the compilation of autopy fails while compiling:

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
```

The fix has been suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993126/errors-while-installing-python-autopy?lq=1). You should download autopy from source and modify the file src/screengrab.c adding at the top of you C file

```
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
```

recompile the file
You could also try to change compiling flags or install libpng from source

Comment: Please can you add more info on your errors? It gives us a better chance to help you

Answer (score 0):

$ git clone git://github.com/msanders/autopy.git

$ cd autopy

add

```
#include "/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Headers/gl.h"

instead of

#include
```

$ python setup.py build

$ sudo python setup.py install

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem and I finally fixed it. Make sure your command line tools are up to date and then build autopy from src. For Xcode 5.1 (OSX 10.9) and Xcode 5.1.1 (OSX 10.10), run the following to download and install the latest command line tools:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Once finished, download autopy:

```
git clone git://github.com/msanders/autopy.git
```

Install autopy:

```
cd autopy && sudo python setup.py install
```

Install Spynner using pip:

```
sudo pip install spynner
```

Hopefully this saves someone out there some time in the future! **Note: In the past I already had the command line tools installed. Since I just updated to 10.10, it appears that I had to reinstall them. Makes sense.