# I have already installed libpng, but there is an error " 'png.h' file not found #include <png.h>" when I am installing the autopy

Tags: python, macos, unix, opengl, libpng

I am a beginner at python, recently I want to install autopy in my Mac (Mavericks,10.9.4). 
    I read many introductions and other people's questions. But I still cannot install the autopy successfully. My steps to install the autopy are as below:

1. I have installed the libpng from the http://ethan.tira-thompson.com/Mac_OS_X_Ports.html
2. I am beginner, I check the /Library/Frameworks and /usr/local and I
   think I have installed the libpng correctly
3. [Terminal]`git clone git://github.com/msanders/autopy.git`
4. According to the introduction, I write `#include <OpenGL/gl.h>` at the seventh line of the autopy file "src/screengrab.c"
5. [Terminal]`cd autopy`
6. [Terminal]`python setup.py build`

And here comes in the command window

```
src/png_io.c:3:10: fatal error: 'png.h' file not found
#include <png.h>
          ^
1 error generated.
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

Do I need to rewrite the file address of "png.h" in the png_io.c?And what should I do to install the autopy on Mac?Do I have some important Omissions?

Comment: If I understand that libpng page correctly, libpng installs its header file in `/usr/local/include/libpng`, and its library in `/usr/local/lib`. You'll need to point the setup procedure of `autopy` to those paths.

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install libpng-dev
```

I am installing autopy right now, and stuck at the same step.  And after installing libpng-dev, the problem resolved. :)

The full process to install autopy is as follow

1. `sudo apt-get install libx11-dev`
   to resolve "#include " not found error
2. `sudo apt-get install libxtst-dev` to resolve "#include " not found error
3. `sudo apt-get install libpng-dev` to resolve "#include " not found error
4. `easy_install autopy`

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem every time I try to install autopy. As Evert mentioned in his comment on your question, your compiler can't find `libpng`. If you have properly installed it via [the link you mentioned](http://ethan.tira-thompson.com/Mac_OS_X_Ports.html), then you can add some environment variables that will help your compiler find it, without having to edit the source code.

Here's a complete example that works for me on OS X Yosemite (10.10.1):

```
git clone git://github.com/msanders/autopy.git
cd autopy
export LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/include/libpng"
export C_INCLUDE_PATH="/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/include/libpng"
python setup.py build
sudo python setup.py install
```

Comment: When I check my `/usr/local/include` directory, there's nothing called `libpng`. I do see `png.h` and `libpng16` in this directory, though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it worked for me

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/libpng12
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libpng12-0
```

Answer (score 0):

After I confirmed that **png.h** was in a default path

```
/usr/local/include/png.h
```

I ran the following command to force these paths as default flags for the build

```
sudo CPPFLAGS='-I/usr/local/include/' LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/lib/' python setup.py build
```

and it worked  (on OS X Yosemite 10.10.5)

Remember to run the **install** version of the command, and to **cd** out of the **autopy** directory before attempting to use AutoPy