# easy_install a python package won't work

Tags: python, ubuntu

I'm trying to install a python package using easy_install but it keeps saying that a file is missing. I have tried 'sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev'

I'm on xubuntu.

```
sudo easy_install autopy
Searching for autopy
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/autopy/
Best match: autopy 0.51
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/a/autopy/autopy-0.51.tar.gz#md5=b92055aa2a3712a9c3b4c874014b450e
Processing autopy-0.51.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-lFRYYC/autopy-0.51/setup.cfg
Running autopy-0.51/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-lFRYYC/autopy-0.51/egg-dist-tmp-WC7CUY
src/snprintf.c: In function ‘portable_vsnprintf’:
src/snprintf.c:569:19: warning: variable ‘starting_p’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
       const char *starting_p;
                   ^
src/png_io.c:3:17: fatal error: png.h: No such file or directory
 #include <png.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Looks to be a problem with libpng. See this answer here.  Is libpng installed? easy_install is unable to detect it. -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25053647/i-have-already-installed-libpng-but-there-is-an-error-png-h-file-not-found

Comment: Thanks for that, it worked.