# png.h file not found - Linux

Tags: linux

I am trying to run [this](http://cvlab.epfl.ch/cms/site/cvlab2/lang/en/software/pom/index.php) in linux ubuntu. When I type make it says

```
rgb_image.cc:26:24: fatal error: libpng/png.h: No such file or directory
 #include <libpng/png.h>
```

Then i followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25053647/i-have-already-installed-libpng-but-there-is-an-error-png-h-file-not-found) to install png.h.

```
sudo install libpng-dev
```

But now its telling me

```
install: missing destination file operand after ‘libpng-dev’
```

What do I do?

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

try  rather this:

```
sudo apt-get install libpng-dev
```

Then maybe go [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com) ;)

Answer (score 4):

For centOS 7 you can try

```
yum -y install libpng*
```

Answer (score 2):

With Ubuntu 18, `/usr/include/png.h` moved to `/usr/include/libpng/png.h`
A workaround is this:
`ln -s /usr/include/libpng/png.h /usr/include/png.h`

Or you can configure your build to use include directory `/usr/include/libpng`

Answer (score 1):

**For Centos 8,** I got the below warning message :

> *Warning: Header file <png.h> not found.
> This host has no libpng library.
> Disabling support for PNG framebuffers.*

and I solved it using the command :

> *sudo yum install libpng-devel*

Answer (score 0):

For Centos 7 use below

- `libpng-devel` : Development tools for programs to manipulate PNG image format files

  ```
  yum install libpng-devel
  ```

Comment: What is the difference compared to the above?