# /usr/bin/sudo: Permission denied in cygwin when installing "libpng-dev"

Tags: cygwin, sudo, yum

I am getting the error as follows in cygwin

```
$ make
g++  -O3 -W -Wall -g  -c -o ImageIOpng.o ImageIOpng.cpp
ImageIOpng.cpp:19:17: fatal error: png.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [<builtin>: ImageIOpng.o] Error 1
```

After followin to this answer. [png.h file not found - Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36674667/png-h-file-not-found-linux][1]),

I had error in the following,

```
$ sudo apt-get install libpng-dev
-bash: /usr/bin/sudo: Permission denied
```

I have read that in Linux, I don't need to write `sudo`, instead of that I can use `yum`. So, I have tried yum install. But, it says

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yum", line 22, in <module>
    import yummain
  File "/usr/share/yum/yummain.py", line 22, in <module>
    import clientStuff
  File "/usr/share/yum/clientStuff.py", line 18, in <module>
    import rpm
ImportError: No module named rpm
```

Almost, in every steps, I am getting errors. What was the problem? yum is very useful package, but it seems installed not correctly.I have installed yum-2.0.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install package on cygwin you need to use its setup as downloaded by
https://cygwin.com

see
https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-net.html#setup-packages
for how to select packages.

yum will not work and please note that Cygwin is not Linux. Most things works in the same way but not all.

Comment: Thank you. After I install the **libpng16-devel** by **setup.exe**, I solved my problem.